# Facet_wrap isn't properly ordering plots by its values

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to arrange my plots by value using `facet_wrap()`, however some of them aren't in sales profit order. Here is the image:

[image: Rplot.png]

My code:

```
Lucro_Categorias %>%
  mutate(Categoria = Categoria %>%
  as_factor() %>%
  fct_reorder(Lucro)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ano, y = Lucro, fill = Categoria, order = -Lucro)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ Categoria, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_tq() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format(prefix = "", suffix = "", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-58u-CscC7tM5o-imy9e4r6jdgxHB5mF/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Matj8gVrYmNy5hL6p8oG_JCEiW01QhT/view?usp=sharing) are the source data files.

How can I move the two black circled plots to where I set the arrow?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the levels of the faceting factor (`Categoria` instead of `Species` in your case).
Here is a more minimal reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# default order of facets (usually alphabetical)
iris %>%
  qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = .) + facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

```r
# set ordering of factes manually
new_order <- c("virginica", "setosa", "versicolor")
iris %>%
  mutate(Species = Species %>% fct_relevel(new_order)) %>%
  qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = .) + facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

```r
# set ordering of factes using another variable
iris %>%
  mutate(Species = Species %>% fct_reorder(Sepal.Width)) %>%
  qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = .) + facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]